# Show another Image Instead App image in Facebook Notification php

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, notifications

i am using Facebook api for sending Notification, My Notification code works fine,
 but i need to show another image instead app image.

if anybody did this earlier please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use any other image in the notification (assuming you are talking of `Notification API`). Only App Icon is visible in the notification.